# Как очистить весь текст от html

Tags: php

На сайте установлен плагин SCEditor и была включена функция копирования кода в месте с текстом, при вставки текста в поле
То есть когда копируешь текст с другого сайта и вставляешь его поле с плагином SCEditor, текст вставляется вместе с кодом html с того сайта
И так получилось, что на сайте уже 7т наименований и во всех присутствует левый код

Вот пример, что храниться в поле

https://jsfiddle.net/jvouk071/

Возможно ли полностью удалить весь html, css код и оставить только текст?

`strip_tags` пробовал, он удаляет только теги, а подобный код `&amp;lt;w:Word11KerningPairs/&amp;gt;` оставляет

Comment: для начала можно обработать текст функцией htmlspecialchars_decode, ну а дальше если не поможет то копать  в сторону регулярных выражений

Comment: Да, есть очень удобная библиотека для этих целей - http://htmlpurifier.org/